# kubectl annotation is too big

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'v created ingress on gke with annotation that have a list of whitelisted ips - the problem is list got too big and cant see whats at the end of it (that's how I see it on `kubectl describe ingress <name>` with the 3 dots at the end)

```sh
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range:
                                   xx, yy, zz ...
```

to the point where I see dots at the end - and after 20+ min of looking cant find command to describe my ingress in a way to get its annotations - any thoughts ?

the ingress itself was made like so

```sh
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
...
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
...
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: {{ index .Values.ingress "whitelist" | quote }}
```

and the list just as plain string with coma delimiter

I thought I could use something like `kubectl describe ingress -o jsonpath='{.metadata.annotations}'` or smth but it doesnt work on `describe` only on `get` commands

Answer (score 1):

Ok answer was way simpler, just running `kubectl get ingress <name> -o json` showed full annotation list

Comment: `kubectl get ingress <name> -oyaml` ;)